# Oracle JPublisher

Tags: oracle

I want to know why we need to use JPublisher? And maybe someone can give good tutorials using Oracle JPublisher for beginners?

Best regards!

Answer (score 2):

[JPublisher](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96658/intro.htm) generates Java wrappers for PL/SQL programs and SQL objects.  I found [this blog entry](http://jts-blog.com/?p=121) that looks quite helpful.

Comment: Blog entry looks removed.